# Find matches of rows equalling over multiple columns

Tags: excel, indexing, match, lookup

I have a worksheet where I am arranging games of players playing each other. There are columns for the players names or numbers for each round. See example image.[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oAU3.png)

What I am after is a way to check if a player has previously played the same player and highlight that players name. So lookup a player and his opponent and see if it matches the row in other columns.

Comment: Are there just three rounds?

Comment: There are actually 5 rounds in my full spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this could be interesting, there are obviously different ways to do this, but without VBA the way to get highlighted cells is through conditional formatting.

Example below is obviously simplified but gives you an idea how you could approach this.

- 1) I created a sheet with three rounds like below:

[image]

- 2) I added conditional formatting to column B, D and F to see if the cell to it's right has the last entered value in it. Like so:

  ```
  =$C4=INDIRECT(CELL("ADDRESS"))
  ```
- 3) Obviously you need reversed formatting for column C, E and G like so:

  ```
  =$B=INDIRECT(CELL("ADDRESS"))
  ```
- 4) Now when adding a 4th Round (you could obviously tweek around to format when you want to create a new row), you enter a value and hit `ENTER`.
- 5) The output will be like so:

[image]

- 6) Matt has played Sarah, Emma and John

:)

**EDIT1:** *Reading your question again, this isn't quite what you need. I'll try tweak it around!*

**EDIT2:** *See below my attempt using VBA, and actually answering your question :)*

- 1) Making use of VBA Worksheet Change Event:

  ```
  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  Dim Player As String, Opponent As String
  Dim C As Range

  'Check if a player name has been entered
  On Error Resume Next
  If InStr(1, Sheets(1).Cells(2, Target.Column), "Player", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
      If Right(Sheets(1).Cells(2, Target.Column).Value, 1) = "A" Then
          Opponent = Target.Offset(0, 2).Value
      ElseIf Right(Sheets(1).Cells(2, Target.Column).Value, 1) = "B" Then
          Opponent = Target.Offset(0, -2).Value
      End If
      Player = Target.Value
      If Opponent <> "" And Player <> "" Then
          Sheets(1).UsedRange.Cells.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
          With Sheets(1).UsedRange
              Set C = .Find(Opponent, Lookat:=xlWhole)
              If Not C Is Nothing Then
                  firstaddress = C.Address
                  Do
                      If C.Offset(0, 2).Value = Player Or C.Offset(0, -2).Value = Player Then
                          C.Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                      End If
                      Set C = .FindNext(C)
                  If C Is Nothing Then
                      GoTo Donefinding
                  End If
                  Loop While C.Address <> firstaddress
              End If
  Donefinding:
          End With
      End If
  End If

  End Sub
  ```
- 2) Paste this in Sheet(1) code
- 3) Make sure row 2 has either "Player A" or "Player B" as a value

What does this code do:

- A - It checks whether you add a name to a Player A or Player B
- B - If so, it will first clear any formatting done in a previous run
- C - Then make use of `.findnext` to get any match of the player just added
- D - Depending on A or B in will check if the opponent next to any found cell is the same
- E - If so, it will highlight those cells

I'm sure the code can do with some cleanup, but it works :)

Comment: Thanks for the initial attempt. What I am really after though is to only highlight if the player has played the same opponent. So for instanc eI fully populate the next round and then it highlights that actually one match is actually one that's happened before. So that I can alter the pairings. I can have a visual basic script added to excel if that makes it easier, But haven't a lot of VB experience myself.

Comment: Use of VBA does change a lot...I'll try it out :)

Comment: @user3001454, I updated the answer with a piece of VBA code. Please give that a go and tell me if it worked for you.

Comment: Works fine, though as another answer above does not use VBA I'll opt for that for final implementation as others I will share the final worksheet to won't understand the VB as easily. Thank you for your effort - hopefully it was an interesting query.

Comment: @user3001454, You'r welcome, I updated the code more to your needs (looking at the layout of your data).

Comment: @JvdV I like the idea of using the worksheet_change event to do this on the fly, as data is entered. That said, I think there will be a problem if someone later deletes a name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Conditional Formatting to do this. See below image:
[image]

The three Tables are called Round1, Round2, Round3. I've added a helper column to hold a Conditional Formatting formula, and stacked them vertically so I can take a screenshot that fits here.

Here's the formulas. Note that they must be array entered using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> keyboard shortcut:

H2:

```
=OR(
         [@[Player A]]&[@[Player B]]=Round2[Player A]&Round2[Player B],[@[Player B]]&[@[Player A]]=Round2[Player A]&Round2[Player B],
         [@[Player A]]&[@[Player B]]=Round3[Player A]&Round3[Player B],[@[Player B]]&[@[Player A]]=Round3[Player A]&Round3[Player B]
)
```

H8:

```
=OR(
         [@[Player A]]&[@[Player B]]=Round1[Player A]&Round1[Player B],[@[Player B]]&[@[Player A]]=Round1[Player A]&Round1[Player B],
         [@[Player A]]&[@[Player B]]=Round3[Player A]&Round3[Player B],[@[Player B]]&[@[Player A]]=Round3[Player A]&Round3[Player B]
)
```

H14:

```
=OR(
         [@[Player A]]&[@[Player B]]=Round1[Player A]&Round1[Player B],[@[Player B]]&[@[Player A]]=Round1[Player A]&Round1[Player B],
         [@[Player A]]&[@[Player B]]=Round2[Player A]&Round2[Player B],[@[Player B]]&[@[Player A]]=Round2[Player A]&Round2[Player B]
)
```

...and here's what you need to add into the Conditional Formatting dialog for the first Table:

[image]

This can fairly easily be amended to handle further rounds, but it's a convoluted and somewhat inefficient approach compared to using say a Dictionary object via VBA.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for the great answer. Does exactly what I want.

Comment: Cool. Please mark the answer as helpful if you found it so.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it myself, using a VBA Dictionary. It processes any Tables that contain the string "Round" in the Table Name.

```
Option Explicit

Sub HighlightDuplicates()

Dim lo As ListObject
Dim lr As ListRow
Dim dic As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sTemp As String
Dim sPlayerB As String
Dim sPlayerA As String

Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each lo In ws.ListObjects
        If InStr(lo.Name, "Round") Then
            lo.Range.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
            For Each lr In lo.ListRows
                sPlayerA = UCase(Intersect(lr.Range, lo.ListColumns("Player A").Range))
                sPlayerB = UCase(Intersect(lr.Range, lo.ListColumns("Player B").Range))
                If sPlayerA > sPlayerB Then
                    sTemp = sPlayerB
                    sPlayerB = sPlayerA
                    sPlayerA = sTemp
                End If
                sTemp = sPlayerA & "|" & sPlayerB
                If Not dic.exists(sTemp) Then
                    dic.Add sTemp, False
                Else
                    dic(sTemp) = True
                End If
            Next lr
        End If
    Next lo
Next ws


For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each lo In ws.ListObjects
        If InStr(lo.Name, "Round") Then
            For Each lr In lo.ListRows
                sPlayerA = UCase(Intersect(lr.Range, lo.ListColumns("Player A").Range))
                sPlayerB = UCase(Intersect(lr.Range, lo.ListColumns("Player B").Range))
                If sPlayerA > sPlayerB Then
                    sTemp = sPlayerB
                    sPlayerB = sPlayerA
                    sPlayerA = sTemp
                End If
                sTemp = sPlayerA & "|" & sPlayerB
                If dic(sTemp) Then
                    Intersect(lr.Range, lo.ListColumns("Player A").Range).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                    Intersect(lr.Range, lo.ListColumns("Player B").Range).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                End If
            Next lr
        End If
    Next lo
Next ws

End Sub
```

And here's the result:

[image]